# IF statement in expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I have an `expect` script as part of a bash function. The script must handle the following:

- depending on the router firmware after logging in the router may or may not say "continue?" where you then need to enter 'y' or 'n' the former drops to the router's shell

How do I do something like the following:

```
if [expect "continue?" then { send "y\r"; exp_continue }]
else exp_continue
```

Thanks.

Comment: no `bash` tag here; this is pure expect.

Comment: I've only included the code for the expect script. This is between EOF tags, i.e. `function myFunc(){ /usr/bin/expect<<EOF [...code...] EOF`

Comment: FYI, you probably want `<<'EOF'`, not `<<EOF`. The latter runs expansions; the former passes your script to expect exactly as it is.

Comment: Elaborate on "expansions"?

Comment: `$foo` is a thing that gets expanded. `$(foo)` likewise.

Comment: ...anyhow -- if the fact that you were calling it from bash were actually relevant, you'd need to have some bash code showing the calling and return-handling convention. The fact that you haven't done so makes it clear that, when asking your question, you considered the fact that you were calling from bash not important enough to demonstrate the details (as would be necessary if someone were going to be debugging anything in those details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set timeout 3 # wait 3 seconds for "continue?"
expect {
  "continue?" { send "y\r"; }
  timeout { }
}
set timeout 10 # return to 10-second default
```